# Bug with 100% width div - Doesn't extend all the way across

Tags: css, html

Here is my code running:

http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/60/

It's quite simple code, but when you make the preview window small and scroll to the right, you can see the bug. The header and footer bars (orange and blue) dont extend all the way across.

I've tried a few things and cant fix it. Anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: There is only 1 thing o want to point out, if you want a full width header, and fixed width content, shoul be more logic to have the header outside of the Wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/HMsKa/61/)***

Hi now define in your body `min-width` of your page

**as like this**

add this `css` in your `stylesheet` and see the demo

................

```
body{
min-width:900px;
}
```

**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/HMsKa/61/)**

Comment: @Dipaks now at least define min-width in your body according to design

Comment: This fixes the problem, but is it the right way of doing it or was there actually something wrong with how I coded the site?

Comment: The solution you posted doesn't work with percent width. You know any workaround for it?

Comment: that worked just fine, i had the same problem but didn't know, just stepped on this question randomly :D

Answer (score 1):

> The header and footer bars (orange and blue) dont extend all the way across.

this is due to the different `width` declaration you assigned: for the `header` you have `width: 100%;` (calculated as the width of the current visible viewport) and for `#main` element you have `width: 900px;` (the footer has no width assigned but, as a block element, its width is 100% by default)

just use the same width (100% or 900px) depending on the layout you want to obtain

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I have 100% so the bar extends all the way across but I want the cotnent to sit in a 900px box in the middle.

Comment: use a wrapper element (for header, main and footer) with `width:900px` and `margin: 0 auto;` then use `width:100%` (or no width) for main, header and footer

Comment: Which is the better solution? Yours needs extra tags but is it more "correct"?

Comment: a wrapper element containing all elements is very common solution. Instead you should assign a width of 900px and margin (if you want them center aligned) to *every* element children of your body.

Comment: @Dipaks, wrap element should have width: 900px.

Comment: Does the wrap go outside the header_container? Do we still need the main "wrap"? If you could show me a quick example on jsfiddle I would really appreciate it

Comment: I am not considering here px (pixel) at all.... everything in percent, and the background shouldn't disappear